# VBA Regex value pairs

Tags: regex, vba

I am new to regex and I am trying to capture a series of key value pairs using a pattern. The values I am looking to capture come with a key, line by line, with an "=" as the separator :

```
Field1        = value1
Field2        = value2
Field3        = value3
```

However, the values could be complicated strings such as :

> 123@example.com
>
> abc- det - FLP
>
> VCN:20161115:74055:5
>
> 99.70

I am implementing this in VBA which apparently does not support regex "lookbehind".

Could someone help me define a regex pattern to capture the values, I am working with the following pattern ( which unfortunately doesn't run because of lookbehind): `(?<=\=\s).+`

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe `Split(text, "=", 2, 1)` will be enough here, then just get the second element. If you need a regex, it will be `=\s*(.+)`, then grab what is in `SubMatches(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
\w+\s*=\s*(\S+)
```

Which will take account of white-space around the `=` and capture the right hand side of the pair.

Code sample:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim objRegex As RegExp
    Dim objMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim varTests As Variant
    Dim varTest As Variant
    Dim strTest As String

    Set objRegex = New RegExp
    objRegex.Pattern = "\w+\s*=(\S+)"

    varTests = Array("Field1=value1", _
        "Field1=123@abc.com", _
        "Field1=abc- det - FLP", _
        "Field1=VCN:20161115:74055:5", _
        "Field1=123=456=789", _
        "Field1=99.70")

    For Each varTest In varTests
        If objRegex.Test(CStr(varTest)) Then
            Set objMatches = objRegex.Execute(CStr(varTest))
            strTest = "Matched: " & objMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            strTest = "No match: " & CStr(varTest)
        End If
        Debug.Print strTest
    Next

End Sub
```